# How to properly use Global variables in perl

Tags: perl

I am a novice to perl. I'm trying to understand it by writing some programs. Scoping in perl is giving me a hard time.

I wrote the following:

```
use 5.16.3;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

Getopt::Long::Configure(qw(bundling no_getopt_compat));
&ArgParser;
our ($sqluser,$sqlpass);

$sqluser="root";
$sqlpass="mypassword";

sub ArgParser {
    print "Username is ".$sqluser." Password is ".$sqlpass."\n";
    my $crt='';
    my $delete='';
    GetOptions ('create|c=s' => \$crt,
        'delete|d=s' => \$delete
    );
    if ($crt) {
        &DatabaseExec("create",$crt);   
    } elsif ($delete) {
        &DatabaseExec("delete",$delete);    
    } else {
    print "No options chosen\n";
    }
}

sub DatabaseExec {
    use DBI;
    my $dbname=$_[1];
    print "Username is ".$sqluser." Password is ".$sqlpass."\n";
    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:", $sqluser,$sqlpass);
    my $comand=$_[0];
    if ($_[0] eq "create") {
        my $db_com="create database ".$dbname;
        print 1 == $dbh->do($db_com) ? "Database created\n":"An error occured while creating database. Maybe it exists?\n";
        #print "Executing: ".$db_com."\n";
    } elsif ($_[0] eq "delete") {
        my $db_com="DROP DATABASE ".$dbname;
        #print "Executing: ".$db_com."\n";
        print 1 == $dbh->do($db_com) ? "Database deleted\n":"An error occured while creating database. Maybe it exists?\n";
    }
}
```

It was my understanding that our would declare these as global variables for the use of the main code, and subroutines. However this gives the following output:

```
#~/perlscripts/dbtest.pl -c hellos
Use of uninitialized value $sqluser in concatenation (.) or string at /root/perlscripts/dbtest.pl line 20.
Use of uninitialized value $sqlpass in concatenation (.) or string at /root/perlscripts/dbtest.pl line 20.
Username is  Password is
Use of uninitialized value $sqluser in concatenation (.) or string at /root/perlscripts/dbtest.pl line 44.
Use of uninitialized value $sqlpass in concatenation (.) or string at /root/perlscripts/dbtest.pl line 44.
Username is  Password is
DBI connect('','',...) failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at /root/perlscripts/dbtest.pl line 45.
Can't call method "do" on an undefined value at /root/perlscripts/dbtest.pl line 50.
```

I would not like to pass these as arguments to the sub, and would rather use them as global variables. Could someone help me determine my misunderstanding of scoping?

Comment: Are you running perl scripts as root without knowing exactly what you are doing? :)

Comment: Well, yes, but this is a VPS on which I do nothing else than test perl, and download torrents. :)

Comment: Still, its a small safety precaution to create a new user with limited privileges.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your variables are not declared when your subroutine is called:

```
&ArgParser;                 # subroutine call
our ($sqluser,$sqlpass);    # declaration

$sqluser="root";            # assignment
$sqlpass="mypassword";
```

In order to use these global variables inside the subroutine, put the subroutine after the variable declaration.

However, using global variables is a bad thing, and you should avoid it whenever possible. You can do this instead, for example:

```
my $sqluser = "root";
my $sqlpass = "mypass";

ArgParser($sqluser, $sqlpass);    # you should not use & in subroutine calls
```

And then inside the subroutine:

```
sub ArgParser {
    my ($sqluser, $sqlpass) = @_;
    ...
```

This way, your variables are nicely encapsulated and safe from being manipulated accidentally.

Regarding the ampersand `&` in your subroutine call, this is documented in [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html):

```
To call subroutines:

NAME(LIST);   # & is optional with parentheses.
NAME LIST;    # Parentheses optional if predeclared/imported.
&NAME(LIST);  # Circumvent prototypes.
&NAME;        # Makes current @_ visible to called subroutine.
```

Comment: If I dont use the ampersand, I get this: "Bareword "ArgParser" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./dbtest.pl line 13.".

Comment: @Droidzone That is because you did not read the documentation that I so thoughtfully pasted into my answer for you. `ArgParser;` is not in the list of valid ways to call a subroutine unless you predeclare the subroutine. Use `ArgParser()`, with parentheses.

Comment: Sorry, I understand now. I've been using subs without declaring them for some time.

Comment: @Droidzone You only need to predeclare if you want to be able to use the sub without parentheses. So, that's not wrong.

Comment: Even if you don't want to switch to passing arguments (and you really should make that change), you can still change your subroutine call from `&ArgParser` to `ArgParser()`.

Comment: "put the subroutine after the variable declaration", I think it's the calls to the sub that need to be after the declaration...

Answer (score 8):

Perl does not have *global* variables. What Perl has are:

- Package variables.
- Lexically scoped Variables.

A package is a *namespace*. In Perl, a namespace is sometimes called a *package*. Your default package name is `main`. For example. This is perfectly legal:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$main::variable = "What? Where's my 'our' or 'my' declaration?";

print "Look, I can print $main::variable without using 'my' or 'our'!";
```

I simply prefix my package variable names with a package, and wham! They exist!

This causes me consternation:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$variable = "What? Where's my 'our' or 'my' declaration?";

print "I'm not going to print 'cause you're going to get a compilation error";
```

With the `use strict;`, you must either declare a variable as `our` or `my`, or prefix it with the name of the *package* it is in.

Package variables are easiest to understand. Package variables are actually stored in a Perl variable structure, so they're always available once declared:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

if ( 1 == 1 ) {  #Yes, I know this is always true
    our $foo = "I have a value!";
}

say "Looks like $foo has a value";
```

Lexically scoped variables are harder to understand. Basically, a lexically scoped variable is in scope in the *block* it's defined, but out of scope once you leave that block. It's also available in sub-blocks:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $foo = "Foo has a value";

if ( $foo ) {   #Always true
    my $bar = "bar has a value";
    print "$foo\n";    # $foo has a value. This is a sub-block
    print "$bar\n";    # $bar has a value. It was defined in this block
}

print "$foo\n";    # $foo still has a value.
print "$bar\n";    # You'll get en error here. $bar out of scope here
```

Here's a few suggestions:

- You don't need to predeclare subroutines. That's just asking for trouble.
- If you define your variables at the beginning of your program, you can use `my` variables, and they'll be available in your subroutines since they'll still be in scope.
- Leave the `&` off of subroutine calls. They cause subtle changes in the way the subroutine works and these *subtle changes* are probably not what you want. Standard is just to call the subroutine.

  - Avoid the `? ... : ...`, especially if you're not using spaces. It makes your program harder to read, and doesn't save any execution time.
  - Pull subroutine parameter into variables as soon as you call your subroutine.
- Perl interpolates variables for you. There's a lot of problems with Perl. It doesn't have real object orientation. It's not a exception oriented language. It's got lots of cruft. One of the big advantages is that you don't have to go through all sorts of machinations to print a variable value. Use it and hold up your head in pride when you hang around Python fanboys.
- Use spaces to make your code easier to read.
- Maybe what you really want are *constants*. `my` variables will work, but constants assure you that these values won't be accidentally changed in your program.

Here's your code rewritten. Note that constants don't have a sigil in front. These normally can't be interpolated in strings. However, if you surround them with `@{[...]}`, you can interpolate them too. I did it both ways below:

```
use 5.16.3;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

use constant {
    SQL_USER => "root",
    SQL_PASS => "mypassword",
};

Getopt::Long::Configure qw(bundling no_getopt_compat);

sub ArgParser {
    print "Username is " SQL_USER . " Password is " . SQL_PASS . "\n";
    my $crt;
    my $delete;
    GetOptions (
        'create|c=s' => \$crt,
        'delete|d=s' => \$delete,
    );
    if ( $crt ) {
        DatabaseExec( "create", $crt );   
    }
    elsif ( $delete ) {
        DatabaseExec( "delete", $delete );    
    }
    else {
        print "No options chosen\n";
    }
}

sub DatabaseExec {
    use DBI;

    my $comand = shift;
    my $dbname = shift;

    print "Username is @{[SQL_USER]} Password is @{[SQL_PASS]}\n";

    my $dbh = DBI->connect(
        "dbi:mysql:",
        SQL_USER,
        SQL_PASS
    );

    if ( $command eq "create" ) {
        my $db_com = "create database $dbname";
        if ( $dbh->do( $db_com ) ) {
            print "Database created\n"
        }
        else {
            print "An error occured while creating database. Maybe it exists?\n";
        }
    } elsif ( $command eq "delete" ) {
        my $db_com = "DROP DATABASE $dbname";
        #print "Executing: ".$db_com."\n";
        if ( $dbh->do($db_com) ) {
            print "Database deleted\n";
        }
        else {
            print "An error occured while creating database. Maybe it exists?\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks a lot for the proper programming guidelines!

Answer (score 0):

A classic resource on variable scoping, which I recommend reading, is [Coping with scoping](http://www.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html) by Mark-Jason Dominus: it describes the fundamental partition in families of Perl variables (package and lexical variables) and warns about some bad practices a beginner might incur in.

Comment: Thank you, but isnt it a bit outdated? It makes no reference to the newer 'our'.

Comment: Rather than outdated, I'd simply say it's old: it lacks latest new things about Perl, but I think it's still valid in his substance. Something it's worth reading, let's say so.

Comment: [`our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html "perldoc -f our") isn't really that new, It has been in Perl [since 5.6.0 back in 2000](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhist.html "perldoc perlhist").